# Getting exit code of last shell command in another script

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, exit-code

I am trying to beef up my notify script. The way the script works is that I put it behind a long running shell command and then all sorts of notifications get invoked after the long running script finished.

For example:

```
sleep 100; my_notify
```

It would be nice to get the exit code of the long running script. The problem is that calling `my_notify` creates a new process that does not have access to the `$?` variable.

Compare:

```
~ $: ls nonexisting_file; echo "exit code: $?"; echo "PPID: $PPID"
ls: nonexisting_file: No such file or directory
exit code: 1
PPID: 6203
```

vs.

```
~ $: ls nonexisting_file; my_notify
ls: nonexisting_file: No such file or directory
exit code: 0
PPID: 6205
```

The `my_notify` script has the following in it:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "exit code: $?"
echo "PPID: $PPID"
```

I am looking for a way to get the exit code of the previous command without changing the structure of the command too much. I am aware of the fact that if I change it to work more like `time`, e.g. `my_notify longrunning_command...` my problem would be solved, but I actually like that I can tack it at the end of a command and I fear complications of this second solution.

Can this be done or is it fundamentally incompatible with the way that shells work?

My shell is Z shell (`zsh`), but I would like it to work with Bash as well.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You'd really need to use a shell function in order to accomplish that.  For a simple script like that it should be pretty easy to have it working in both zsh and bash.  Just place the following in a file:

```
my_notify() {
  echo "exit code: $?"
  echo "PPID: $PPID"
}
```

Then source that file from your shell startup files.  Although since that would be run from within your interactive shell, you may want to use $$ rather than $PPID.

Answer (score 6):

It is incompatible. `$?` *only* exists within the current shell; if you want it available in subprocesses then you must copy it to an environment variable.

The alternative is to write a shell function that uses it in some way instead.

Answer (score 3):

One method to implement this could be to use EOF tag and a master script which will create your my_notify script.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f my_notify ] ; then
rm -rf my_notify
fi

if [ -f my_temp ] ; then
rm -rf my_temp
fi

retval=`ls non_existent_file &> /dev/null  ; echo $?`
ppid=$PPID
echo "retval=$retval" 
echo "ppid=$ppid" 
cat >> my_notify << 'EOF'
#!/bin/bash

echo "exit code: $retval"
echo " PPID =$ppid"
EOF

sh my_notify
```

---

You can refine this script for your purpose.